# When taking an input of "T | undefined" can you return a type of "T"?

Tags: typescript

In the following code `sureReturn` should return a concrete type of `T` (`string` in the example). Instead I get `string | undefined`.

Is there a way to definitely return a non `undefined` type?

```
interface Things {
    a?: string
}

const things: Things = {
    a: 'Hi'
}

function sureReturn<T>(val: T): T {
    if (val === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Nothing')
    }
    return val
}

const thing = sureReturn(things.a) // string | undefined - should only be string
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAtQHMDOyDeAUMicnAPwBcyOYU2hAvoYQgPYi3JiYi7UZseALwFipONQDkACWBSmLGAFcQCMMA41lUCACUIYHSAA8qAHwAKAG5wANgICUAsaWTAYyG-eTC-yVQATCBhQCEDHVzdSHig2AHdkEAhEgFEoOKhLKQA5Nh5sKUdxEmY3XSMoEGRbO0VWDi4Cvl9tXQNKkEtm3AA6OEiAekGaOmxkAB8AkGDQ5MDkAFoadDZlOwWOOwBPZAAjFFp6PiA

Comment: How about to define a return type for `maybeReturn`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `| undefined` to `val` in `sureReturn`. This will make the compiler infer `T` as `string` even when `string | undefined` is passed in:

```
const myVar = ''

function maybeReturn(val?: string) {
    return val
}

function sureReturn<T>(val: T | undefined): T {
    if (!val) {
        throw new Error('Nothing')
    }
    return val
}

const thing = sureReturn(maybeReturn(myVar)) // string
```

Another option is to use conditional types (`Exclude` will do it), but the first option is preferable, conditional types will cause issues in the implementation:

```
function sureReturn<T>(val: T): Exclude<T, undefined> {
    if (!val) {
        throw new Error('Nothing')
    }
    return val as Exclude<T, undefined> // assertion needed
}

const thing = sureReturn(maybeReturn(myVar)) // string
```